# How can I show the "Open with" file dialog?

Tags: c#

Is there any simple way to open the "Open with" file dialog?

Comment: Winforms? WPF? Webforms? MVC?

Comment: CodeProject has an article which comes top when searching Google: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/openwith.aspx. However, I'd like to see a prettier way of doing this, rather than resort to externs (`ProcessStartInfo`, perhaps?).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32153874/5306861

Answer (score 28):

Some reverse-engineering with ProcExp revealed a rundll32.exe command line that worked.  Here's a sample program that uses it:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;

class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        ShowOpenWithDialog(@"c:\temp\test.txt");
    }
    public static void ShowOpenWithDialog(string path) {
        var args = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.System), "shell32.dll");
        args += ",OpenAs_RunDLL " + path;
        Process.Start("rundll32.exe", args);
    }
}
```

Tested on Win7, I cannot guess how well this will work on other versions of Windows.

Comment: Thank you @Hans! I was hitting around the bush for a while and this is what I needed. I wasn't using the full path of shell32.dll.

Comment: Note that `OpenAs_RunDLL` is undocumented and [does not always work.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23566667/rundll32-shell32-dll)

Comment: I would replace Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.System) with Environment.SystemDirectory. It is shorter and has the same result.

Comment: Old question (but still relevant!), but Harry Johnston's answer in his linked comment to use `SHOpenWithDialog` is the better answer I believe. With that said, I tried Han's answer on Win10 1909 and it worked fine with the handful of types I tested with.

Comment: [What’s the guidance on when to use rundll32? Easy: Don’t use it](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130104-00/?p=5643).

Answer (score 12):

This ought to do the trick...

```
var processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(fileName);
processInfo.Verb = "openas";
Process.Start(processInfo);
```

Although, Oded makes a great point - not knowing exactly how/where you intend to use such functionality means this might not be the answer for your situation.

Recent comments on this answer go to show I wasn't very detailed in the first place. A problem will arise if you try to `openas` a file that already has the `open` verb defined against that type of file. Similarly, if you try to `open` a file that doesn't have that verb defined there'll be trouble. The issue would be:

> Win32Exception: No application is associated with the specified file for this operation

Off the top of my head I suggested to Thomas that in order to use this kind of code in a production application you would need to be thorough and perhaps check the registry, or otherwise find out whether or not a file can and should be opened with any given verb. It could be simpler than that when you consider [`ProcessStartInfo.Verbs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.verbs%28VS.90%29.aspx): this will, once the `fileName` is set, provide you with a collection of possible verbs associated with the file type. This should make it easier to determine what to do with which file.

To wrap up, as I mentioned to Thomas, you will need to take care and add some complexity/intelligence to your application - this answer certainly isn't a catch-all solution.

Comment: Doesn't work... Win32Exception, "No application is associated with the specified file for this operation"

Comment: @ThomasLevesque It will only work if no 'default programs' are defined; that is to say, if there is a `Open with...` context menu for the file then this will fail. If it's an unknown file type with simply an `Open` option then this will work. The reverse is also true: using the `open` verb for known file types will launch the default program but wil lraise this same exception if unknown. So, in a proper application you want to be thorough about this; maybe doing a lookup in the known file types repo (registry) and basing your decision of how to open on facts given by the system.

Comment: @ThomasLevesque In fact, you don't even need to go to such lengths: [`ProcessStartInfo.Verbs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.verbs(VS.90).aspx) will be populated with the possible verbs for a file when the `fileName` is set, meaning you can just check if the `open` verb is defined and if not use `openas`. This doesn't catch all cases I bet, so add your own cleverness at will.

Comment: Thanks @ThomasLevesque, this was very useful to me. With `ErrorDialog`, you can open **unassociated files** in file system as when you open it from a folder in windows explorer, showing the dialog to browse apps. Without this, my app was crashing when opening unassociated files.

Comment: -1 My understanding is this only works if the files doesn't have a default application, which is not any different than just calling Process.Start on the file name itself. Did I miss something?

Answer (score 2):

Using

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(path);
```

The file will be openened with the default program, if no default program is defined the open with dialog will be shown.

You can use the the function:

```
[DllImport("shell32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
extern public static bool 
       ShellExecuteEx(ref ShellExecuteInfo lpExecInfo);
```

You have an example to use this function on: [this link](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/openwith.aspx)

Answer (score -3):

There are tons of [shell examples](http://1code.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=WinShell) in the [All In One Code Framework](http://1code.codeplex.com/). Maybe you can take a look at them to see whether an example has functions you want to have.