# SHOpenWithDialog analog for windows XP?

Tags: c++, windows

I need to open `"OpenWith"` dialog , where user can select program which will open some file, for example `.xml`.
In vista and grater it can be done via `SHOpenWithDialog` , but I need to support windows XP as well.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I show the "Open with" file dialog?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4726441/how-can-i-show-the-open-with-file-dialog)

Answer (score 0):

```
 bool BrowseOpenWith(const HWND hwnd, LPCTSTR lpszFilename)
{
ASSERT(!IsBadStringPtr(lpszFilename,INFINITE));
ASSERT(_tcslen(lpszFilename));

if (hwnd) {
    ASSERT(IsWindow(hwnd));
}

const CString strCmd=
    TEXT("shell32.dll,OpenAs_RunDLL ")
    +CString(lpszFilename);

const int nRet
    =(int)ShellExecute(hwnd,TEXT("open")
    ,TEXT("Rundll32.exe")
    ,strCmd
    ,NULL
    ,SW_SHOW);

return (nRet>32);
}
```