# How to invalidate MUICache?

Tags: c#, windows, registry

I've modified my C# application name by right clicking on project -> Application -> Assembly information -> Title.

If the application is already installed then it is not updating the name because it is pulling the application name from MUICache which is not getting refreshed.

I'm trying to find out a way where I can make MUICache get invalidated programmatically so that it will update the application name appropriately.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following method to delete the value in the `MuiCache` key that contains the path to your application executable.

After that value has been deleted from `MuiCache`, browsing to your application via the Windows [Open with](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4726441/1497596) dialog will re-add the path to your executable to `MuiCache` with your updated title.

```
using Microsoft.Win32;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

const string MuiCacheKeyPath =
    @"Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\MuiCache";

static void DeleteExecutablePathFromMuiCache()
{
    string exePath = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location; // (1)

    using (RegistryKey muiCacheKey = Registry.CurrentUser
        .OpenSubKey(MuiCacheKeyPath, writable: true))
    {
        if (muiCacheKey.GetValueNames().Contains(exePath))
        {
            muiCacheKey.DeleteValue(exePath);
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, if you want to programmatically update the title directly, instead of `DeleteValue(exePath)`, call:

```
muiCacheKey.SetValue(exePath, yourNewTitle);
```

---

(1) From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/837501/1497596) to the question [How can I get the application's path in a .NET console application?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/837488/1497596).