# Open file with compatible applications

Tags: c#, mono, gtk#

I am trying to reproduce [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/akSJW.png) with gtk#, how can I get the list of compatible extention with a specific file ? (in my case .cpp, .hpp)

I tried this :

```
Process.Start(@"C:\foo.jpg");
```

but it's only opens the default app.

Comment: if you want an open with native dialogue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4726441/how-can-i-show-the-open-with-file-dialog  If you on the other hand want the individual program names etc. you'd probably have to read them from the regestry under HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\ .jpg\OpenWithList  - thats for windows only obviously, but since you tagged this mono i thought i'd mention it

Comment: Gnome registers file types and their compatible applications in the so called MIME Database, https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/desktop_migration_and_administration_guide/file_formats so you can get started from there.

Comment: Thank you, I will take a look